# Sublime Plugin EventListener get changes

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I want all changes in Sublime Text Editor 3 show in real time on a website. I would like to write a plugin that sends only the changes to an API.

Can the EventListener `on_modified` I somehow tell what has changed? With `view.change_count ()` I will not get only the number of the change.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class KeyBindingListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified_async(self, view):
        print("The on_modified event fired!"+str(view.change_count()));
```